# typeorm ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint

Tags: typescript, postgresql, typeorm

I'm trying to create a postgres database using typescript and typeOrm. but when I'm trying to add a new user with the following code I get this error:

```
// Adds a user to the database
console.log("Inserting a new user into the database...");
const user = new dbUser();
user.discord_id = idToSave;
user.username = nameToSave;
user.email = mailToSave;
user.checked_in = checkToSave;
user.checked_in_until = standardDate;
user.command_active = activeToSave;

await connection.manager.save(user);

db_1 | 2021-04-30 10:16:47.031 UTC [34] ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pg_type_typname_nsp_index"

db_1 | 2021-04-30 10:16:47.031 UTC [34] DETAIL: Key (typname, typnamespace)=(users_update_update_id_seq, 2200) already exists.

db_1 | 2021-04-30 10:16:47.031 UTC [34] STATEMENT: CREATE TABLE "users_update" ("update_id" SERIAL NOT NULL, "update_time" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, "description" character varying(300) NOT NULL, "userUserId" integer, CONSTRAINT "PK_e032645fede0887997de5ea8460" PRIMARY KEY ("update_id"))
```

This only happens when the database is empty. if the code is ran a second time it works correctly, but we want it to work instantly. these are the entities used.

User Entity:

```
import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, OneToMany } from "typeorm";
import { AgendaRequest } from "./AgendaRequest";
import { Update } from "./Update";
import { Standup } from "./Standup";
import { Retrospective } from "./Retrospective";
 
@Entity({ name: "users" })
export class User {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    user_id!: number;

    @Column({ type: "varchar", length: 25})
    discord_id!: string;

    @Column({ type: "varchar", length: 32})
    username!: string;

    @Column({ type: "varchar", length: 50})
    email!: string;

    @Column()
    checked_in!: boolean;

    @Column()
    command_active!: boolean;

    @Column({ type: "timestamp"})
    checked_in_until!: Date;

    @OneToMany((type) => AgendaRequest, (agendaRequest) => agendaRequest.user)
    agenda_requests!: AgendaRequest[];

    @OneToMany((type) => Update, (update) => update.user)
    updates!: Update[];

    @OneToMany((type) => Standup, (standup) => standup.user)
    standups!: Standup[];

    @OneToMany((type) => Retrospective, (retrospective) => retrospective.user)
    retrospectives!: Standup[];
}
```

Update Entity:

```
import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, ManyToOne, JoinColumn } from "typeorm";
import { User } from "./User";

@Entity({ name: "users_update" })
export class Update {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    update_id!: number;

    @ManyToOne((type) => User, (user) => user.updates)
    @JoinColumn()
    user!: User;

    @Column({ type: "timestamp"})
    update_time!: Date;

    @Column({ type: "varchar", length: 300})
    description!: string;
}
```

I hope someone can help us with this.